# Select floor() em oracle

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Em MySQL seria o equivalente de

```sql
SELECT floor(4.5);
```

Como fazer o mesmo em Oracle PL SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mesmo

```
select floor(4.5) from dual 

FLOOR(4.5)
----------
         4
```

Answer (score 0):

Da seguinte forma:

```sql
SELECT floor(4.5) FROM dual;
```